# Libgit2 how to discard/revert changes if the file

Tags: libgit2

I'm searching a way to discard all changes of file with path.

in libGit2Sharp there is exist method

```
CheckoutOptions options = new CheckoutOptions { CheckoutModifiers = CheckoutModifiers.Force };

repo.CheckoutPaths("49916", checkoutPaths, options);
```

but I see no similar method in [libgit2 API](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD)

How can I reset file to start state of head's commit?

---

I do not need unstage changes -- I need exactly revert SINGLE file to state of head commit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git_checkout_tree`. Pass `NULL` for the `treeish` to reset to the HEAD commit. Pass the path(s) you want to reset in `opts.paths` and set `opts.checkout_strategy` to `GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE`. You probably also want to or `GIT_CHECKOUT_DISABLE_PATHSPEC_MATCH` into `checkout_strategy` to disable wildcard matching.

Comment: already tried this and it isn't worked for me =( for both git_checkout_tree and git_checkout_index

Comment: (setting `opts.path` + `checkoutStrategy` to `.Force` ); Didn't did `DISABLE_PATHSPEC_MATCH`. As result - it's delete all of files that was changed, but not files written into `opts.path`

Comment: I have added code comments for being sure that you will understand swift https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIOh.png

Comment: `git_checkout_index` will only do what you want if the index matches the HEAD. If the file is already staged, it won't do anything. I don't understand swift well enough to know if you've initialized `opts` and `opts.paths` correctly.

Comment: I use this func only with unstaged paths. As you see, there is comment above function "discardChanges" that tells that we can do this only with unstaged files :)

Comment: I use this func only with unstaged paths. If you look on the screenshot one more time, you will see comment above function "discardChanges" that tells that we can call it only with unstaged files :)

Comment: I use the same way initialisations in another places and there all works fine. So my problem of the code that it discards all changes (except files that wasn't added to repository earlier) instead of discard only files configured inside of opts.paths. Generally all you saw on the screenshot is mix of Swift and C code. This is not clean swift.

Comment: and about that `opts.paths` can be assigned incorrectly, you can look on the following screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ys6.png . It is shows that they are assigned correctly -  only one path in array, path is relative. And absolutely sure path is existing in repo. And instance of options created as well. Because of checkout can be done :) No error was throwned.